# ModelAndView not rending via JQuery

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I am trying to render ModelAndView from an AJAX call. The hit goes to the controller and it is returning ModelAndView. However, when I try to render that object via $(#div).html(response), it simply displays a blank page. I used $(#div).text(response) to check if I am receiving HTML response and I do. The HTML response I am receiving is of the whole page and not just the DIV fragment I am returning in ModelAndView. I am completely confused since I have used this approach sucessfully in different project. Below are the code snippet:

**Javascript file>>>**

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: contextPath + "/order/orderMiscDetails/"+orderNo,
    success: function(response) {
        $("#divPayment").empty();
        $('#divPayment').html(response);
        //ajaxCallEnd();
    }
});
```

**Controller Code>>>>**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "order/orderMiscDetails/{orderNo}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView orderMiscDetails(@PathVariable("orderNo") String orderNoStr, 
        Model model) throws Exception {

    Long orderNo = 0l;

    System.out.println("Called>>>>>>>>>>>>>>orderMiscDetails>>>>>>>>");

    CustomerOrder customerOrder = new CustomerOrder();
    customerOrder.setOrderNumber(orderNo);
    customerOrder = orderAdminService
            .getCustomerOrderByOrderNo(customerOrder);


    Map<String,Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    modelMap.put("customerOrder", customerOrder);
    ModelAndView mv= new ModelAndView("order/payment_history",modelMap);
    System.out.println(mv.toString());

    return mv;
}
```

**DIV Fragment JSP>>>>**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

```
            <div class="heading">PAYMENT HISTORY</div>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <th width="30">S.No.</th>
                    <th>Transaction Date</th>
                    <th align="right" style="text-align: right;">Transaction
                        Amount</th>
                    <th>Transaction Type</th>
                    <th>Transaction ID</th>
                    <th>MATransaction ID</th>
                    <th>Reason</th>
                    <!-- <th width="100">Action</th>-->             
                        </tr>
                <c:forEach items="${customerOrder.orderTransactions}"
                    var="orderTransaction" varStatus="loopStatus">
                    <%-- <c:if test="${orderTransaction.orderTransactionStatus eq '0'}">  --%>  

                    <tr id='transaction_${orderTransaction.ordertransactionID}'>
                        <td>${loopStatus.index+1}</td>
                        <td>${orderTransaction.date}</td>
                        <td align="right">
                            ${customerOrder.landing_page_id.currencies.currencies_symbol} ${orderTransaction.transactionAmt}
                        </td>
                        <td>${orderTransaction.transactionType}</td>
                        <td>${orderTransaction.transactionID}</td>

                        <td><c:if test="${empty orderTransaction.mATransactionID}">N/A</c:if>${orderTransaction.mATransactionID}</td>
                        <td>${orderTransaction.reason}</td>
                        <%-- <input type="hidden" id="param1" value="${orderTransaction.ordertransactionID}"/> --%>
                     <!--   <td><a onClick=deleteOrderTransaction();>Delete</a></td> -->
                    </tr>
                <%--  </c:if>  --%>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
```

Can there be something wrong with Spring settings?

**SOLUTION:**

I was able to solve this. However, the solution is very weird and I have no idea how is it working!

For some reason, jquery's .html() is not working. It worked when I replaced
$('#divPayment').html(response);
by
document.getElementById('divPayment').innerHTML = response;

JQuery is included properly since I am using throughout the same JSP. Whatever it is, thanks everyone!

Comment: is ajax call successfully returning?

Comment: My guess is that there might be something wrong with your response syntax... meaning there might be a missing element tag or something.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Yes. It is sending back response. However, it return HTML of complete page and NOT just the DIV Fragment JSP.

Comment: @Lochemage: Honestly, I don't think so because I replaced the DIV Fragment JSP code with simple one line text. Still, it rendered blank page.

Comment: have your tried to set `datatype: "html"` in your ajax yet?

Comment: @Culyx: Yes. But no luck.

Comment: Solved. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try?

```
html = $.parseHTML(response);
// first build html structure from the response 
$('#divPayment').html(html);
// And after insert this html into the payment div
```